# Weird lines on android chrome for responsive gallery (Flexslider, bootstrap.js)

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, flexslider

Have a look at this responsive layout I'm trying to set up:

http://www.marcopragliola.com/sites/exp/layout.php

I've implemented responsive bootstrap.js and a responsive web gallery (FlexSlider).

My issue is that when I display or scroll the gallery on Android phone and tablet with Chrome, strange horizontal lines appear across the gallery. It's fine on desktop browser at any size.
Any idea about the issue?

Answer (score 0):

It is normal on touch devices. Define your CSS something like this.

```
.removeOutline{
 -webkit-tap-highlight-color:rgba(0,0,0,0);
}
```

and add this class to your gallery like this.

```
<div class=".removeOutline">
    <a href="#">Any text</a>
</div>
```

You can use

```
-webkit-tap-highlight-color:transparent;
```

But it would work only on iOS devices. Hope it'll help you.

Comment: No, I don't think it's normal at all; I'm not talking about tap highlights but about horizontal streaks containing parts of the photo in the gallery. Have you tried the URL on an Android device?